# SonarQube doesn't start

Tags: java, jvm, sonarqube

I am running Ubuntu server and trying to install SonarQube. The problem is I don't get any usefull message in the error log.

It's hosted on Ubuntu Server 14.04

I followed [this tutorial](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-sonarqube-continuous-inspection-on-ubuntu-14-04/) basically. MySQL was already installed and I skipped Nginx for now.

**Logs:**

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.06.16 08:29:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.06.16 08:29:43 TRACE app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] tryToMoveTo from INIT to STARTING => true
2017.06.16 08:29:43 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from INIT to STARTING => true
2017.06.16 08:29:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms1G -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process4612386175293439883properties
2017.06.16 08:29:43 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STARTING to STARTED => true
2017.06.16 08:29:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2017.06.16 08:29:50 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STARTED to STARTING => false
2017.06.16 08:29:50 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from INIT to STARTING => true
2017.06.16 08:29:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx1G -Xms1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process42380044775043463properties
2017.06.16 08:29:50 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from STARTING to STARTED => true
2017.06.16 08:29:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.06.16 08:29:56 TRACE app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] tryToMoveTo from STARTING to STOPPING => true
2017.06.16 08:29:56 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from STARTED to STOPPED => true
2017.06.16 08:29:56 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from STOPPED to STOPPED => false
2017.06.16 08:29:56 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo ce from INIT to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:29:56 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:29:56 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STARTED to STOPPING => true
2017.06.16 08:30:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] tryToMoveTo from STOPPING to STOPPED => true
2017.06.16 08:30:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] tryToMoveTo from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo ce from INIT to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STOPPING to STOPPED => true
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STOPPED to STOPPED => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STOPPED to STOPPED => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] tryToMoveTo from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo ce from INIT to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo web from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
2017.06.16 08:30:15 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STOPPED to STOPPING => false
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there some other log file? There is no hint about the reason in what you have posted.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I am also confused. If you google for "SonarQube is stopped" etc you'll find people pointing to an error in this file.. I don't know where Java (Oracle) stores their log files?

Comment: Please post your $SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log.

Comment: Hi Eric, whoops I wasn't aware of the web.log. It seems that SonarQube was unable to connect to my database!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry!

Eventually I found out that the problem was in the web.log (thanks Eric Hartmann) where it was giving an error on connecting to the database.

Comment: With every SonarQube upgrade I have to relearn the lesson that there is no longer a single `sonar.log` anymore! :P